# Not getting inbox messages by email

Tags: support, notifications

On the upper bar on all SE sites, there is a "Stack Exchange" dropdown with "hot questions / all sites / inox / notifications" sections. On the bottom of it, there is a "email settings" option with "Email me my unread inbox messages". I'm not getting any email notifications, and my email address is correct in the textfield there. What could be happening?

Comment: They are delayed by about 24 hours if I remember correctly.  Have you waited that long?

Comment: I have **never** received notification email, ever.

Comment: I hope it's clear that you get your unread messages on email, and checking the notification bar marks all as read.

Comment: Hm, makes perfect sense.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand what I mentioned in the comments, you get notifications of *unread* inbox messages, not all inbox messages.

(Un)fortunately, clicking on the MultiCollider (aka the Stack Exchange notification dropdown menu) marks **all** messages as read, which is what I assume is causing you to not get any emails.

Comment: Interestingly, on the mobile, it doesn't remove any unclicked notifications from the menu, so there's *some* read/unread logic behind it. But the counter is still reset. They should fix this at some point.

Comment: @slhck weird, it still does so for me. You should try jmort's extension http://stackapps.com/questions/3778